# MSDN: Add or Remove Application Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn, application-settings

I just googled on how to use Application Settings and came up with the following
[msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/25zf0ze8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It describes to ways to add Application Settings at design time in VS 2010. One using the Project-Properties and a second using the Properies-Window for a selected `control`.
I tried the second one, but there simply is no node `Data` or a property `ApplicationSettings` under it. Is the article outdated? (although it states there that it applies to VS2010) Or have I overlooked something else? I vaguely remember seeing some such property in an older VS version but I am not sure about that.

Edit: My project is a WPF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application setting binding in the Properties window is only supported for Winforms projects, not WPF.